# Simulate the remote host identification warning

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris

I need to simulate the warning:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!  @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

I have two Linux machines and when I do `ssh` from Linux1 to Linux2, `ssh` accepted and reports no problem.

But because some of testing, I want to simulate the - **Identification Has Changed error**

So what I need to edit on the remote server in order to create the problem?

**what I did until now** is to change the knwon_hosts on both machine but its not create the problem

I get this:

```
 key_read: uudecode AAAAB3NzaC1y3jrzG62xyHrb3qxc9eYpg1Cp1PrRElTFfYbEHsRfTZU21S8kO5/Tq+ED8=
 failed
 key_read: uudecode AAAAB3NzaC1y3jrzG62xyHrb3qxc9eYpg1Cp1PrRElTFfYbEHsRfTZU21S8kO5/Tq+ED8=
 failed
 The authenticity of host 'sfe1 (10.106.164.111)' can't be established.
 RSA key fingerprint is 84:82:2b:80:ca:3f:57:c7:8c:14:44:dd:b9:70:e5:d8.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```